# Can I give multiple address parameters to a payable function?

Tags: solidity, payable

Newbie here, making my very 1st Smart Contract (a rock/paper/scissors game).

I'm using 0.5.11 because that's what the tutorial I'm learning from is taught in.

I'd like to call my payable `placeBet` function with 3 parameters:

1. The wager
2. The address of Player 1
3. The address of Player 2

**I want Player 1 and Player 2 to send the wager amount to my contract.**

But I'm having trouble implementing this.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem with the current code? With the current code anyone can deposit Ethers in the contract with `placeBet` so it should work. The only thing needed for depositing Ether is the `payable` keyword in the function name - no other code is needed.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen The problem is I only want the 2 players to be able to deposit ether, the contract should be locked to everyone else. I also want the 2 players to deposit the exact same amount, only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current logic is not working, because if you are not using `.transfer(msg.value)`, but using `.transfer(<ETHER_VARIABLE>)` then transfer method is using the contract balance to send the ether. Apparently you contract has 0 balance, because you are not forcing users to actually deposit the ethers into the contract balance on method `placeBet`.

One solution might be to force both users to deposit the ethers into the contract balance at method `placeBet()` and allow them to play only when both did made the deposit. Then on method `play()` the contract will have enough balance to send ethers to the winner (because players previously made their deposits). This way you should also build `withdrawDepositedAmount` method for the scenario when player 1 deposit ether amount and player 2 dissapear and not finishing the deposit, so player 1 not end up with "locked" ethers.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you want only those two players to be able to deposit, and the deposit amount has to be the same.

So what you need is:

1. Anyone else sending Ethers to the contract causes a `revert` so the transaction is reverted. This can be done with a `require`
2. Whenever Player1 or Player2 (whichever is first) deposits an amount you wait for the other one to store the exact same amount - revert if different
3. Revert if the wager amount is zero

You don't need to check for address balances because the wager should already be in - they don't need to have double the required wager. So the Ether is already stored in the contract at the start of the function.

So something like this should work:

```
uint wagerAmount;

function placeBet(uint _wager, address payable _address1, address payable _address2) external payable {
    require(msg.sender == _address1 || msg.sender == _address2);
    require(msg.value > 0);
    if (wagerAmount == 0) {
        // if this value is not set yet, set it. This is the first player to set the wager
        wagerAmount = msg.value;
    }
    else {
        require(wagerAmount == msg.value);
        // start game
    }
}
```

Note that the code allows one player to play against himself, but I guess that's ok.

Also, as a general security note, this kind of game is superly flawed: the other player can wait for the other player to send his move and then send a transaction which wins whatever the other player chose.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that security issue? Can I make it so that the transactions are only sent after both players pick their move? Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm just starting out. Thanks!

Comment: It's a very valid and common question, no worries :) There is no trivial way around it - you can consider something like hashing the answers with a salt, for example, and both parties reveal their salts once the betting transactions are in.